# Can't inject $q in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, q

everyone.

I have a really strange (for me) problem here. I am trying to inject the $q lib in one of my controllers and when I try to console.log() it, it returns "undefined". I am injecting the same library in one of my services, and it's working there! Let me show you:

The service:

```
(function() { 'use strict';
  angular
  .module('app.grid')
  .factory('GridData', GridData);

  GridData.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
  function GridData($http, $q) {
...
```

The controller (not working):

```
(function() {
'use strict';
  angular
  .module('app.grid')
  .controller('GridCtrl', GridCtrl);

  GridCtrl.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', 'GridData', '$q'];
  function GridCtrl($log, $scope, GridData, $rootScope, $q) {
    console.log($q); // Returns "undefined"
...
```

I wonder if any of you guys had had this same problem before? It's probably something real stupid, like it always is, but I can't see it for some reason :(

Cheers,
H

Comment: DenimChicken, James Allardice: I knew it's stupid. Thank you so much for the help! I don't know if I can accept both your answers, but will try :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the $rootScope to your $inject array:

```
GridCtrl.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', 'GridData', '$rootScope', '$q'];
```

Or remove it from the argument list if it's not needed:

```
function GridCtrl($log, $scope, GridData, $q) {
```

Answer (score 3):

You have one too many arguments:

```
GridCtrl.$inject = ['$log', '$scope', 'GridData', '$q'];
function GridCtrl($log, $scope, GridData, $rootScope, $q) {
  //                                      ^
}
```

You're not injecting `$rootScope`. The `$q` service will be available inside your controller, it will just be referred to by `$rootScope` instead of `$q`. Remove that and it should work! Alternatively, add `'$rootScope` to the dependency array.